# Construct angularjs model from laravel 5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5

I have a form and the value of every field generated from Laravel5 blade. Here is how I construct the form

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'pay', 'name' => 'checkoutForm']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('cs_cvcode', 'CV CODE') !!}
    {!! Form::password('cs_cvcode', ['class' => 'form-control', 'ng-minlength' => 3, 'ng-maxlength' => 3, 'required', 'ng-model' => 'checkout.cs_cvcode']) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('od_notes', 'TESTING SANDBOX', ['ng-model' => 'checkout.od_notes', 'ng-value' => 'checkout.od_notes', 'ng-update-hidden']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Pay', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'ng-click' => 'processCheckout($event)', 'ng-disabled' => '!checkoutForm.$valid']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

from here you can see I'm trying to bind the value to angular's model. But this does not work for the hidden input. The form will not send the value of hidden input if I use `$http.post`.

What do you suggest for the hidden input value attach to the model of AngularJS. Here is the workaround of my `js` code inside the controller

```
$scope.checkout = {};
console.log($scope);
$scope.processCheckout = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/pay",
        transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
        //headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        data: param($scope.checkout)
    });
    request.success(function() {
        console.log($scope);
    })
}
```

why it does not bind to `$scope.checkout`